# golang syntax error at or near "$1" in postgres

Tags: postgresql, go

I am trying to execute a query in go using the sql module.

```
var from string = "2015-03-01 00:00:00"    
rows, err := db.Query("select time, val from table where " +
                              "time >= extract(epoch from timestamp with time zone $1)::int4 " +
                              "and time < extract(epoch from timestamp with time zone '2015-03-01 00:15:10')::int4 " +
                              "order by time asc",from)
```

However I get the error

```
pq: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

If I put in the epoch values directly then the query will work and the query works when I try it without any variables i.e. with the query hardcoded.
So what is the problem?

Comment: have you tried `?` and not `$1`

Comment: It gives the same error (i.e. `syntax error at or near "?"`). Anyway, I thought that the pq module used `$1` ?

Comment: hmmm... can you try and make your query a single multi-line string using backticks? Not that I think it would matter but otherwise things seem okay, and it's a better practice in terms of GC pressure and cpu performance anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right about `$1` and `?`.

The reason why it complains about invalid syntax with `$1` is because of type cast. Put it like this:

```
rows, err := db.Query("select time, val from table where " +
                          "time >= extract(epoch from $1::timestamp with time zone)::int4 " +
                          "and time < extract(epoch from timestamp with time zone '2015-03-01 00:15:10')::int4 " +
                          "order by time asc",from)
```

Comment: @Tino when you say `"You're right about $1 and ?."`, what do you mean by it?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: @Obi Wan - PallavJha you have to specify its type